# Unbounded linear operator with closed null space

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear operator between Banach spaces $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ which is defined everywhere in $\mathscr{X}$. Could $T$ have a closed null space $N(T)=\{x \in \mathscr{X}|Tx=0\}$ and at the same time be unbounded? I have learnt many examples of unbounded operators, but either their domain are not complete, or they are defined with the help of Hamel basis thus do not have closed null space.

Comment: Using Hamel bases it is easy to build an unbounded isomorphism from an infinite dimensional space to itself.  It is enough to send each basis vector to a big multiple of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible to achieve an empty kernel. Let $T \colon X \to Y$ be unbounded, but otherwise arbitrary. Then, we can define $\hat T \colon X \to \hat Y = X \times Y$ via $\hat T(x) = (x, Tx)$. Obviously, $\hat T$ is still unbounded, but $N(\hat T) = 0$.